# Import Data from MongoDB Atlas and store dictionaries into dataframe for ML

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mongodb-atlas

I have COVID 19 data in MongoDB Atlas. I am able to extract it in python. I want to convert it into Dataframe to be able to use it for Machine Learning. Tried various combinations but was not able to do the same. Help needed.

```
mydata = collection.find({}, {"province_state": 1, "date": 1, "value": 1})
    for items in mydata[0:10]:  # first 11 entries
        print(items)
```

**Output:**

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5fa4d27f66b012d562223715'), 'province_state': 'Alabama', 'date': '1/25/20', 'value': 0}
{'_id': ObjectId('5fa4d27f66b012d562223729'), 'province_state': 'Alabama', 'date': '2/14/20', 'value': 0}
{'_id': ObjectId('5fa4d27f66b012d56222372b'), 'province_state': 'Alabama', 'date': '2/16/20', 'value': 0}
{'_id': ObjectId('5fa4d27f66b012d56222372e'), 'province_state': 'Alabama', 'date': '2/19/20', 'value': 0}
{'_id': ObjectId('5fa4d27f66b012d562223739'), 'province_state': 'Alabama', 'date': '3/1/20', 'value': 0}
{'_id': ObjectId('5fa4d27f66b012d56222373d'), 'province_state': 'Alabama', 'date': '3/5/20', 'value': 0}
{'_id': ObjectId('5fa4d27f66b012d5622237ba'), 'province_state': 'Alabama', 'date': '7/8/20', 'value': 12}
{'_id': ObjectId('5fa4d27f66b012d5622237c3'), 'province_state': 'Alabama', 'date': '7/17/20', 'value': 20}
{'_id': ObjectId('5fa4d27f66b012d5622237c4'), 'province_state': 'Alabama', 'date': '7/18/20', 'value': 20}
{'_id': ObjectId('5fa4d27f66b012d5622237d8'), 'province_state': 'Alabama', 'date': '8/7/20', 'value': 21}
```

Now I want to store this in pandas, please need help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read the data from the collection into the dataframe using this line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(mydata)
```

to get the entire collection:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(mydata))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the query result to a list and directly create a pandas DataFrame out of it.

```
mydata = collection.find({}, {"province_state": 1, "date": 1, "value": 1})
df = pd.DataFrame(list(mydata))
```